# Signing data in C++ compatible with PHP's openssl library

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, signing

I'm looking for a way to sign some data in C++ code which will then be sent to a PHP script for verification and processing. I want to use the OpenSSL module there, namely the *[openssl_verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php)* function so I need something compatible with that.

The application will be only for Windows so CryptoAPI might be fine but looking at the samples I don't like it and couldn't get it work, some simple lightweight library would be better. I just need to load a private key and generate the signature for some string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the Cripto API [this example](http://alexkr.com/source-code/2/importing-secret-key-in-cryptoapi/) might help you to import a custom private key.
Alternatively, you can look at [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is originally a C Library, take a look at its [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html).

*edit:*
Alternatively, have you looked at the [CryptoAPI sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx)? It does signing as well and you should be able to strip the code you need out of it.